# How to install dev version using versioning with asterisk in python/pip?

Tags: python, versioning, requirements

How to install a dev. version (e.g `0.2.dev0+gebdc597` generated by for example [setuptools_scm](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm/#default-versioning-scheme)) of a package?

I tried this

```sh
pip install my-package==0.2.*
```

and failed. Unfort. i can't paste the exact error, but it was something like `couldn't find this version, <list of found versions>`

Also, i'd like to use it later in `requirements.txt`/`install_requires`, so i need a way which works both with `pip` and `setuptools`. I hope it's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is use

```
$ pip install pkg>=0.2.0.dev
```

or in `requirements.txt`

```
pkg>=0.2.0.dev
```

Other options are

`Pip` has a special switch [`--pre`](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-prereleases) which allows to install even with `*`

```
$ pip install --pre pkg==0.2.*
```

or in `requirements.txt`

```
--pre
pkg==0.2.*
```

This topic is also covered in [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/).